# How to pass fixture data to the url in cy.request()

Tags: api, cypress, fixtures, string-interpolation

I am trying to pass fixture data to the url of a post request. Can someone pls help
Below is my code:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.clearLocalStorage()
  cy.fixture('companyId.json').then(function (id) {
    this.id = id
  })
}) 

it('Test', function() {

  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://abc.abc.com/admin/collection/{this.id}',
  }).then((response) => {
    headerCookie = response.requestHeaders.cookie
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the string delimiters around the URL property to back-ticks. That allows the string template to insert the id.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.clearLocalStorage()
  cy.fixture('companyId.json').then(function (id) {
    this.id = id
  })
}) 

it('Test', function() {

  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `https://abc.abc.com/admin/collection/${this.id}`,  // back-ticks and ${}
  }).then((response) => {
    headerCookie = response.requestHeaders.cookie
  })
})
```